# iOS Autolayout how to maintain layout and aspect ratio with differing screen sizes, types and orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, autolayout

I'm having a frustrating time with auto layout and storyboards (probably because I do not use it enough - I tend to construct UIs using code as I find this useful when moving between platforms, however I would like to try and resolve this using a visual storyboard).In the image below, I have shown the basic layout I am trying to achieve.

1) Image 1 & Image 2 (Red) should only be visible on iPhones with the notched screen for example they would be on an iPhone 11 but not an iPhone 8.

2) Image 2 should fill the entirety of the 'notched' unsafe area at the top of the screen - pinned to top and resizing as necessary

3) Image 1 should fill the entirety of unsafe area at the bottom of the screen - pinned to bottom and resizing as necessary

4) Image 4 should be pinned to top of safe area and to both left and right edges. Its height should automatically adjust to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

5) Image 3 should be pinned to bottom of safe area and to both left and right edges. Its height should automatically adjust to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

*Another view will sit over the top of the safe area this will contain the content - but I will get to that later.

The layout needs to work on iPhones & iPads portrait and landscape. It seems like it should be easy but its driving me mad! However I set the constraints I can not seem to get it to behave the way I want!

The idea is Image 2 is an extension to the top of Image 4, and Image 1 is an extension of the bottom of Image 3. There will be no controls over Images 1 & 2 it is purely a visual thing.

Anyway appreciate any advice, thanks in advance :-)

[image: example of layout]

Answer (score 0):

Drop **Image 4** and give it constraints of safe area from top. On top of that after adding constraints, drop **Image 2** just above **Image 4** and add the constraints attaching **Image 2** bottom to **Image 4**.

This above process will make your **Image 2** resize accordingly.

Now for **Image 1** follow the same process. Drop **Image 3** first, add constraints to it. In the remaining space add **Image 1**.

Comment: That worked ok, but realised when switching to landscape that image 1 & 2 are then displayed in the unsafe areas (left *& right) when going to landscape I would like to hide these images and stretch image 3 & 4 to full width, is this possible without code?

Comment: I am not sure of any possible way of doing it without the code.